# Compare two csv files and export the difference in XLS using in C#

Tags: c#

I have to find out difference between two CSV files and highlight the difference (in red colour) in a excel file (delta file). What I am doing is reading csv files into an array

```
string Delta = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName + "\\Reports\\Delta\\";
var sourceFile = File.ReadAllLines(sourceReportDir + "\\" + sourcefName);
var targetFile = File.ReadAllLines(targetReportDir + "\\" + sourcefName);

var diffSourceFromTarget = FindDifferences(sourceFile, targetFile);
var diffTargetFromSource = FindDifferences(targetFile, sourceFile);

if(diffSourceFromTarget.Length > 0 || diffTargetFromSource.Length > 0)
{
    List<string> diffs = new List<string>();
    diffs.Add(sourceFile[0]);

    diffs.AddRange(diffSourceFromTarget);
    diffs.AddRange(diffTargetFromSource);

    deltaFileCreate.CreateDelta(sourcefName, diffs);
}

private static string[] FindDifferences(string[] linesFirst, string[] linesSecond)
{
    return (from line1 in linesFirst
    let isLineEqual = linesSecond.Any(line2 => line1 == line2)
    where isLineEqual == false
    select line1).ToArray();
}


public void CreateDelta(string sourceFileName, List<string> csvDifference)
{
    string deltaDir = Delta + "\\" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyddMM_HHmmss");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(deltaDir);
    File.WriteAllLines(deltaDir + "\\" + "Delta_" + sourceFileName, csvDifference);
}
```

However, this is writing only the difference into a file. Can someone help me to write the delta into an excel sheet all the rows highlighting the difference in RED.

Comment: Probably a check of count of lines first. If that is different, files are different. If same, do a for loop with an integer and compare the strings by index for both arrays. Could even use File.EnumerateLines to avoid big memory usage and enumerate each file one by one.

Comment: Thanks, and any way to export to an Excel?

Comment: Just name it xlsx and excel should do the right thing